# forcing https with www & subdomain without https htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https, subdomain

I need help for my htaccess config.

my following htaccess lock like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+-abc.*|def|www)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

Result: 
all works fine but this domian will not redirect me to https:

```
domain.com => https://www.domain.com [fail]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make first part optional in host name:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:(.+-abc.*|def|www)\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```